# Why the sibling applies the cross mainAxisAlignment?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new in Flutter and I have created the following widget:

```
class Registration extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[Text("Hello1")]),
        ),
        Expanded(child: Text("Hello2")),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

it looks:

[image]

I would like to know, why the text `Hello2` is also placed in the middle of screen. I did not tell it explicitly.

What I am trying to achieve is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Row** and **Column** all have default alignment even you didn't assign any value. Here is the source of Column:

```
...
Column({
  Key? key,
  MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
  MainAxisSize mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
  CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  TextDirection? textDirection,
  VerticalDirection verticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
  TextBaseline? textBaseline,
  List<Widget> children = const <Widget>[],
}) : super(
...
```

To your question:

> why the text Hello2 is also placed in the middle of screen. I did not tell it explicitly.

It is because `crossAxisAlignment` is default **CrossAxisAlignment.center**.

You can get more reference about flutter layout/constraint here: [Flutter Layout Cheat Sheet](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e) and [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Answer (score 1):

You can align Hello2 with Align Widget. By default Hello2 is placed at the beginning of the second Expanded which takes half the screen.

```
class Registration extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[Text("Hello1")]),
        ),
        Expanded(child: Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,child:Text("Hello2"))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You can achieve the same with a Container in place of Align.

To understand wrap you zones with containers and add colors:

```
class Registration extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.green,child:Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[Text("Hello1")]),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child:
                Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("Hello2"))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

The Expanded widget takes all the space available. if you put 2 or more Expanded widgets in a column, they will share equally the available space unless you specify a different flex property for one of them. By default flex = 1 for an Expanded widget.

Flutter widget of the week (Expanded):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo